# How to properly use an Activity with a Fragment within?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-view

I'm trying to get an `Activity` which will work with a `Fragment` (I will work with more fragments later). I created both a class and a layout for such `Fragment`, and included them at `Activity`'s layout.

#### Classes

This is what my `Activity` class looks like:

```
public class Expressa extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is what my `Fragment` class looks like:

```
public class MessageFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText messageField;
    private onNewMessageListener  listener;

    public View OnCreateVie(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_fragment_layout,container,false);

         messageField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.messageField);

        return view;
    }

    public void doTextToSpeech(View view) {

        String text = messageField.getText().toString().trim();
        new TextToSpeechServices().execute(text);
    }

    public interface onNewMessageListener {

        public void newMessage(String msg);

    }

}
```

#### Layouts

`Activity` layout:

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/messageFragment"
        class="apps.android.expressa.expressa.MessageFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/message_fragment_layout" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment's:

However I'm always getting an `IllegalStateException` complaining `MessageFragment` didn't create a view.

This is [fragment's layout](http://pastebin.com/9WkGSErC) and this is [complete stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/i0rWAQc3). I'm using compile SDK API 22, build tools version 21.1.2 and min SDK is 16.
What have I got wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IllegalStateException` is thrown because Android does not detect an implementation of `onCreateView()` in the `MessageFragment`. You have spelled the name of the `onCreateView()` method incorrectly.

Replace

```
public View OnCreateVie(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

with

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

With the correct method signature and the `@Override` annotation, the framework will correctly interpret that you have specified a `View` for the `Fragment`.

Comment: I fixed the typo, thanks  but **actually** it should be `onCreateView`

Comment: What's best way to relate the layout with the class? I ask because I have a button at the Fragment class and the onClick attribute would look any method at Activity ...

Comment: I expected the onClick property of a widget to look for such method at the fragments class where layout belongs to

Comment: I understand now. What you can do is create an `onClickListener` and set it using `button.setOnClickListener()`